# Merge Sorted Linked Lists with head node and without new nodes (void function)

Tags: c, merge, linked-list, mergesort, singly-linked-list

I am writing a void function `void merged_lists (cell * l1, cell * l2, cell * l3);` who receives two linked lists, headed by *l1* and *l2*, whose content is ordered in non-decreasing order, and
generate a new list headed by *l3* that contains the elements of *l1* and l2 ordered.

If the list headed by *l1* is *l1* -> 1 -> 7 -> 9 -> 10 -> NULL and headed by *l2* is *l2* -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 -> NULL, for example, the output must be *l3* -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> NULL

This is a problem with a known resolution, but I'm trying to solve it ***without allocate any new cells in function***, just manipulating the pointers from nodes of *l* to be in *l1* and *l2*.

My approach:

```
typedef struct cell {
    int data;
    struct cell *next;
} cell;

void merged_lists (cell * l1, cell * l2, cell * l3){

    if(l1->next == NULL)
        l3 = l2->next;
    if(l2->next == NULL)
        l3 = l1->next;
    if(l1->next->data <= l2->next->data)
        l3 = l1->next;
    else
    {
        l3 = l2->next;
        l2->next->next = l1->next;

    }

while(l1->next && list2->next) {
    if (l1>next->data > l2->data) {
    //Step 1. Save the next pointer
      Node *tmp = l1->next; 
    //Step 2. Change next pointer to point L2
      l1->next = l2;
    //Step 3. Move L2 to temp
      l2= tmp;
    }
    //Step 4. Move L1 ahead
    l1 = l1->next;
  } 
  if (!l1->next)
 l1->next = l2;





}
```

In the main function I will pass *l3* as the parameter to `print(cell * head)`

Some tip on how to fix the solution?

Comment: Where do the `list1` and `list2` variables all of a sudden come from?

Comment: Can you clarify what is going wrong, please?

Comment: l1 and l2 have already been allocated before calling the function.

Comment: Yes, `l1` and `l2`, but I don't see `list1` and `list2` even though they are used in the if guard.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I will correct.

Comment: You either need `cell **l3` or you need to return the pointer to the first element off the merged list. Modifying the existing `l3` in  the function doesn’t alter anything outside the function.

Comment: Or, [just do this](https://pastebin.com/UZnVLZjX), which imho is much easier to follow.

Comment: `void merged_lists (cell * l1, cell * l2, cell * l3){` <<-- why does this function return void? It seems natural to return a pointer to the resulting list.

Comment: @JohnPetterson - having to allocate a dummy cell isn't an issue in C, because it supports pointers and pointers to pointers. It is normally used in Java for merging lists, to compensate for not having the equivalent of a pointer to pointer, by using dummy.next for the merged list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function declaration

```
void merged_lists (cell * l1, cell * l2, cell * l3);
```

is invalid because the pointers are passed by values. That is the function deals with copies of original pointers to head nodes of lists. As a result the original pointers will not be changed.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell 
{
    int data;
    struct cell *next;
} cell;

size_t append( cell **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        for ( ; ( i < n ) && ( ( *head = malloc( sizeof( cell ) ) ) != NULL ); i++ )
        {
            ( *head )->data = a[i];
            ( *head )->next = NULL;
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

void display( const cell *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

cell * merged_list( cell **list1, cell **list2 )
{
    cell *list3 = NULL;

    cell **current = &list3;

    while ( *list1 != NULL && *list2 != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *list2 )->data < ( *list1 )->data )
        {
            *current = *list2;
            *list2 = ( *list2 )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *current = *list1;
            *list1 = ( *list1 )->next;
        }

        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    for ( ; *list1 != NULL; current = &( *current )->next )
    {
        *current = *list1;
        *list1 = ( *list1 )->next;
    }

    for ( ; *list2 != NULL; current = &( *current )->next )
    {
        *current = *list2;
        *list2 = ( *list2 )->next;
    }

    return list3;
}

int main(void) 
{
    cell *list1 = NULL;
    cell *list2 = NULL;

    int a1[] = { 1, 7, 9, 10 };
    int a2[] = { 2, 3, 8 };

    append( &list1, a1, sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 ) );
    append( &list2, a2, sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 ) );

    display( list1 );
    display( list2 );

    putchar( '\n' );

    cell *list3 = merged_list( &list1, &list2 );

    display( list1 );
    display( list2 );
    display( list3 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 7 -> 9 -> 10 -> NULL
2 -> 3 -> 8 -> NULL

NULL
NULL
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> NULL
```

The function `merged_list` can be written shorter

```
cell * merged_list( cell **list1, cell **list2 )
{
    cell *list3 = NULL;

    cell **current = &list3;

    while ( *list1 != NULL || *list2 != NULL )
    {
        if ( *list1 == NULL || ( *list2 != NULL && ( *list2 )->data < ( *list1 )->data ) )
        {
            *current = *list2;
            *list2 = ( *list2 )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *current = *list1;
            *list1 = ( *list1 )->next;
        }

        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    return list3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can resolve this without the `tmp` variable. Once you override the pointer of the next item in list 1, you basically lose access to all the items in list 1 after the current one. So unless you store that last slice of the list in a temp variable, it's impossible.